# Relation between a representative of a conjugacy class and corresponding irreducible character value

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Is there a relation between the representative order of a conjugacy class and the corresponding irreducible character value? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the question you're asking? By "representative order" it sounds like you're asking whether there is a relationship between $\chi(x)$ and $|x|$ for $x\in G$. The other possibility is you're asking about a relationship between $\# C_g$ (where $C_g$ is a conjugacy class) and $\chi(C_g)$ (where this is the constant value taken by $\chi$ on $C_g$). Are either of these interpretations correct? If so, which?

Comment: And to add to the question by Alex, in either interpretation my next question would be "which irreducible character?".

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Voting to close

Comment: Yeah I mean is there a relationship between χ(x) and |x| for x∈G

Comment: And you did not specify over what fields are these representations taken. Per chance this matters not?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are taking an element $x \in G$, and an irreducible character $\chi$, and asking what influence does the order $n = \lvert x \rvert$ of $x$ have on $\chi(x)$.

In this generality, I do not think you can say much more than the fact that $\chi(x)$ is the sum of some $n$-th roots of unity.

This is because, if $\rho$ is a representation corresponding to $\chi$, then $\rho(x)^n = \rho(x^n) = \rho(1) = I$, where $I$ is an appropriate unit matrix, so the minimal polynomial of $\rho(x)$ divides $x^{n} - 1$, and all eigenvalues of $\rho(x)$ are $n$-th roots of unity.